# Omitted optional input set to null instead of undefined

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-server

So a year or so ago, an update was made on `apollo-server` (or `react-apollo` ?) which completely broke the old use of omitted nullable inputs in GraphQL requests.

Prior to the update, you could define something like :

```
Mutation {
  editProfile(id: ID!, name: String, avatar: String)
}
```

And when calling it client-side with omitted inputs, say :

```
editProfile(id: "whateverid", name: "James")
```

you got `avatar` as `undefined` in your resolver.
**Now it's set to `null`.**

The problem is : `null` is a perfectly valid value for some optional inputs, for instance `avatar`. So basically, we've lost an information in the process and are no longer able to tell the difference server-side between :

- A optional input which was omitted and appears `null` (= do **not** update the database), and
- A optional input that was explicitly set to `null` (= update the database)

I opened a thread on Github about it here : https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/2056

Another guy did the same a year ago on `react-apollo`'s Github : https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1569

dacz posted [an interesting response](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1569#issuecomment-359725254) that sums it up quite well :

> Nullable input when not presented within the query variables in apollo client, is getting called with null value.
>     Client should not pass the whole input as null, it should omit it completely or pass it with undefined. Passing null may mean explicitly null the input. Same applied to input fields, so the server may react on explicitly resetting the value (presented in the input with null or do not handle it if omitted).

Both threads still remain unsolved.

Does someone have any clean solution to this ?

Comment: If this is an issue, it's not an issue with `apollo-server` -- you can easily test this using Playground with the latest version. Omitted input fields will be undefined inside your resolver. That's how GraphQL.js has worked for as long as I can remember.

Comment: I just tested this behavior using apollo-boost@0.3.1, apollo-client@2.5.1 and react-apollo@2.5.3 and I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Both arguments and fields of input objects show up as undefined if they are omitted. The results are consistent whether I use literal values or variables. Even if I explicitly set a variable to undefined, it's still undefined server-side. The only way I can see a null server-side is to explicitly set the value to null.

Comment: It's possible that this was a bug with either apollo-client or react-apollo that was recently fixed. However, if you've updated your libraries and you're still seeing this behavior, there's some other factor that's responsible for it (probably client-side). Narrowing down what that is would require seeing some actual code.